# Get a reference to the elements of a xml schema using XmlSchema

Tags: c#, .net, xsd

I want to use the class XmlSchema to parse a schema but I can't find how to get a reference to the Image and Size elements in the schema below. I'm working on an app that will have a form based on a schema.

I have the schema:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="Test">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Image" type="FileUpload" />
        <xs:element name="Size" type="xs:int" />
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:simpleType name="FileUpload">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string" />
  </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

What about this..?

```
foreach(var size in doc.Root.DescendantNodes().OfType<XElement>()
        .Select(x => x.Size).Distinct())
{
    Console.WriteLine(size);
}
```

or

```
foreach(var image in doc.Root.DescendantNodes().OfType<XElement>()
        .Select(x => x.Image).Distinct())
{
    Console.WriteLine(image);
}
```

you could also use XPATH

```
XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument(); 
xdoc.Load(path to your xml schema file);
XmlNodeList list = xdoc.SelectNodes("//Image");
XmlNodeList list2 = xdoc.SelectNodes("//Size");
```

Comment: I did this, but I want to use the XmlSchema as it provides a more "elegant" way to access the constraints... thanks anyway!

Comment: Also, it will ensure that the schema is valid